# Apache mod_evasive doesn't load

Tags: linux, centos, apache-2.2

I am on a VPS (CentOs) running Apache and I would like to install Mod_Evasive. The problem is that I follow the installation steps without error but Apache doesn't load the module. Here are the step that I have done.

1)  wget http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/mod_evasive_1.10.1.tar.gz

2)  tar xzf mod_evasive_1.10.1.tar.gz

3)  cd mod_evasive

4)  apxs -cia mod_evasive20.c

5) nano /etc/httpd/conf/mod_evasive.conf

6) paste that in the .conf:

```
   <IfModule mod_evasive20.c>
   DOSHashTableSize 3097
   DOSPageCount  2
   DOSSiteCount  50
   DOSPageInterval 1
   DOSSiteInterval  1
   DOSBlockingPeriod  10
   DOSLogDir   /var/log/mod_evasive
   DOSEmailNotify  admin@email.com
   DOSWhitelist   127.0.0.1
   </IfModule>
```

7) nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
  Add :

```
 LoadModule evasive20_module modules/mod_evasive20.so
 Include "/etc/httpd/conf/mod_evasive.conf"
```

8) mkdir /var/log/mod_evasive

9) /etc/init.d/httpd restart

10)  php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep -i evasive

The last command show nothing about mod_evasive. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @dok Did you check httpd error log for any errors

Comment: @SandeepKrishnan yes and I haven't see any error concerning evasive

Answer (score 3):

> 10) php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep -i evasive

This command only shows information about your PHP stack, it does not talk to Apache or mod_evasive().

To have server info on your phpinfo(); you have to run it from a server, so watch the output from a browser.

Or use

```
apachectl -M
```

(Instead of apachectl, you may need to put apache2 or apache2ctl, depending on your installation)

Comment: Alright, but phpinfo() from a browser doesn't contain anything regarding mod_evasive neither.

Comment: The module being loaded should be enough. Check also in the logs, maybe mod_evasive writes something in it. If it's a standard Apache installation with mod_evasive, running a slowloris attack should be enough to test. If the server stays up during the attack and after, it means that mod_evasive works well. See http://ha.ckers.org/slowloris/

Answer (score 1):

You added mod_evasive to Apache and then checked if it existed in PHP on the command line.  `phpinfo()` in a browser is different from `phpinfo()` on the command line.

Try `apachectl -M`

Comment: Alright, but phpinfo() from a browser doesn't contain anything regarding mod_evasive neither.

Comment: And what did `apachectl -M` show?

Comment: evasive20_module (shared) is in the list of module. Does it means that it's running with the setting set in the configuration file? I do not see any way to figure out how well it's working or not.

Comment: That means that it's definitely loaded into Apache.  To test it, you could try triggering its rules.  Running `curl` in a loop or `ab` (probably with some amount of concurrency) from your home connection should be enough to get it to block you.